# How to validate a column in a jtable that can accepts only mobile numbers?

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

This is what i did;but this code fails in some situations like if we enter 9874561231 this number cannot be inserted.

```
tbl.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(text){

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        // throws exception if parsing failes, and it's catched on stopCellEditing
        return  Integer.parseInt((String) super.getCellEditorValue());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        boolean result = false;
        try{
          result = super.stopCellEditing();
          ((JTextField)getComponent()).setBackground(Color.WHITE);
          lblEnterNumbersOnly.setVisible(false);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          ((JTextField)getComponent()).setBackground(Color.RED);
          lblEnterNumbersOnly.setVisible(true);
          result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
        // reset color when begin editing
        ((JTextField)getComponent()).setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        return super.isCellEditable(anEvent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because the value 9874561231 exceed int max value.

You can either change your validation to:

1. Use `Long.parseLong()` for supporting a bigger value.
2. Use regex to check your string

Comment: I would like to do one more validation like that the cell must accept only 10 numbers.How can i modify this code?

Comment: You mean 10 digits only? You can first check the length of String first by string.length, so if it meets your requirement then parse the value (For using Long.parseLong). If you use regex, you can do it more simply.

Comment: For regex, the pattern is /^[0-9]{1,10}$/.  If you think this answer is helpful, please accept it.

Comment: Are you using String.mathces(regex)?  If yse, the regex is "[0-9]{1,10}". The above one is using Pattern and Matcher class